# gnome gmail not working in unity

Tags: 14.04, gmail

I am trying to set gmail as the default email application in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Right now, the only option available at :

```
System Settings -> Details -> Default Applications -> Mail
```

is `Thunderbird Mail`.

Another post([Making Google Calendar and Gmail the "Default Applications" for calendar and mail](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67381/making-google-calendar-and-gmail-the-default-applications-for-calendar-and-mai)) suggests to install the Gnome Gmail package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnome-gmail/files/Version_1.8.2/.

I still don't see the gmail option after installing it. Any solution?